# How to create the drop-down list in kivy with .kv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a problem in creating the drop-down list in .kv so can anybody please help me and give me the code of just a dropdown of 1-10 numbers

Comment: if possible please provide a complete .py and .kv file

Answer (score 0):

You can use [official documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.dropdown.html?highlight=dropdown#module-kivy.uix.dropdown) as a reference

.kv

```
<CustomDropDown>:
    Button:
        text: 'My first Item'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 44
        on_release: root.select('item1')
    Label:
        text: 'Unselectable item'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 44
    Button:
        text: 'My second Item'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 44
        on_release: root.select('item2')
```

.py

```py
class CustomDropDown(DropDown):
    pass

dropdown = CustomDropDown()
mainbutton = Button(text='Hello', size_hint=(None, None))
mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)
dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))
```

Comment: Give outputs please

Comment: i am unable to run it it is showing only blackscreen thats why i am asking for the full code please help me out